# Multer Uploaded Image

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image, express, multer

I am using multer to uplaod images. I can upload them to my database with extension. Everything look perfect but I cannot see them on my webpage.

Also note that my project needs specific images for every different articles that means in every article images changes.

**This is my article.js relevant codes:**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})
const upload = multer({storage: storage})


// Add Submit POST Route
router.post('/add',upload.single('img'),  function(req, res){

  req.checkBody('title','Title is required').notEmpty();
  //req.checkBody('author','Author is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('body','Body is required').notEmpty();

  // Get Errors
  let errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors){
    res.render('add_article', {
      title:'Add Article',
      errors:errors
    });
  } else {
var article = new Article({
    title: req.body.title,
    author: req.user._id,
    img:  `uploads/${req.file.filename}`,
    body: req.body.body,
   });

    article.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
      } else {
        res.render('add_article', {
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**And:**

```
// Get Single Article
router.get('/:id', function(req, res){

  Article.findById(req.params.id, function(err, article){
    //User.findById(article.author, function(err, user){
      res.render('article', {
        article:article,
        //imagePath: article.img,
        //author: user.name
      });
    });
  });
```

This is my article.pug:
    extends layout

```
block content
  br
  //h5 Written by #{author}
  h1= article.title
  p= article.body
  img.img-responsive(src=article.img)
```

Also I havent forgotten enctype or file upload stuffs in my add_article.pug page. But still I cannot understand why it is not uploading.

This is my console.log(article.img): `uploads/image.jpeg`

But still I cannot understand why I cannot see them. Every answer will be apreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213490/discussion-on-question-by-o-alp-eren-gul-multer-uploaded-image).